# Implementation of long list selector in wp7

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-7.1

Is it necessary to use Grouping class for long list selector? In my application i am using a simple list control for holding a large amount of data. Now i feel some performance issues (memory and loading) issues with the ordinary list. So i decided to change my list to  long list selector. My doubt is that is it possible to use same Item template and item source for implementing long list. In an example i found a grouping class. Does this grouping is necessary?? If no is the answer how i can implement this with my existing data. Thanks in advance .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do need to group your data by some type of field, so you'll have a list of groups, and inside each group, the list of items for that group!

I think [this](http://www.windowsphonegeek.com/articles/wp7-longlistselector-in-depth--part2-data-binding-scenarios) is one of the best articles that explains how the LongListSelector should be used!

Comment: In my case i am getting already sorted data; and no need to group it again. My requirement is just hold all my data in my longlist

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need group data, just set: `IsFlatList = true`